# Port with VLAN not working on Cisco switch

Tags: cisco, switching, vlan

I'm having issues with a cisco SG550X-24 switch.

The switch is showing 100U as an administrative VLAN but not an operation VLAN. I'm unsure why this is, and plugging into this port doesn't work. The switch functions normally and other ports work fine.

Screenshot of config page attached:

[cisco vlan config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5412y.png)

1 and 19 are configured exactly and same, port 19 works fine with 100U but port 1 doesn't.

Any ideas? Is there a setting I'm missing that disables the port or VLAN?

Thanks

```
config-file-header
CB-BR-Radon233
v2.5.5.47 / RTESLA2.5.5_930_364_286
CLI v1.0
file SSD indicator encrypted
@
ssd-control-start
ssd config
ssd file passphrase control unrestricted
no ssd file integrity control
ssd-control-end cb0a3fdb1f3a1af4e4430033719968c0
!
!
unit-type-control-start
unit-type unit 1 network gi uplink te
unit-type unit 2 network gi uplink te
unit-type unit 3 network gi uplink te
unit-type unit 4 network gi uplink te
unit-type unit 5 network gi uplink te
unit-type unit 6 network gi uplink te
unit-type unit 7 network gi uplink te
unit-type unit 8 network gi uplink te
unit-type-control-end
!
port jumbo-frame
vlan database
vlan 2,69,100,201
exit
voice vlan oui-table add 0001e3 Siemens_AG_phone________
voice vlan oui-table add 00036b Cisco_phone_____________
voice vlan oui-table add 00096e Avaya___________________
voice vlan oui-table add 000fe2 H3C_Aolynk______________
voice vlan oui-table add 0060b9 Philips_and_NEC_AG_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00d01e Pingtel_phone___________
voice vlan oui-table add 00e075 Polycom/Veritel_phone___
voice vlan oui-table add 00e0bb 3Com_phone______________
link-flap prevention disable
no boot host auto-config
no boot host auto-update
bonjour interface range vlan 1
hostname IMS-CB-BR-Radon233
no passwords complexity enable
username root password encrypted 777f99c04f34de13899c397960ac60d7548cfeb4 privilege 15
username cisco password encrypted ffd1c8e37222f7a9f61aec3e1179e951695fdeba privilege 15
ip ssh server
snmp-server location CB-BR-Radon233
snmp-server contact 
clock timezone J 0 minutes 0
!
interface vlan 1
 ip address 192.168.1.233 255.255.255.0
 no ip address dhcp
!
interface vlan 2
 name Phone
!
interface vlan 69
 name Dirty
!
interface vlan 100
 name Admin
 ip address 192.168.100.233 255.255.255.0
!
interface vlan 201
 name Mocap
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 no switchport
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport trunk native vlan 100
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 storm-control broadcast level 10
 storm-control multicast level 10
 port security max 10
 port security mode max-addresses
 port security discard trap 60
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1
 macro description ip_phone_desktop
 !next command is internal.
 macro auto smartport dynamic_type ip_phone_desktop
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
 storm-control broadcast level 10
 storm-control multicast level 10
 port security max 10
 port security mode max-addresses
 port security discard trap 60
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1
 macro description ip_phone_desktop
 !next command is internal.
 macro auto smartport dynamic_type ip_phone_desktop
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
 storm-control broadcast level 10
 storm-control multicast level 10
 port security max 10
 port security mode max-addresses
 port security discard trap 60
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1
 macro description ip_phone_desktop
 !next command is internal.
 macro auto smartport dynamic_type ip_phone_desktop
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
 storm-control broadcast level 10
 storm-control multicast level 10
 port security max 10
 port security mode max-addresses
 port security discard trap 60
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1
 macro description ip_phone_desktop
 !next command is internal.
 macro auto smartport dynamic_type ip_phone_desktop
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
 channel-group 1 mode auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport trunk allowed vlan none
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport trunk native vlan 100
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
 channel-group 1 mode auto
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1
 channel-group 2 mode auto
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/2
 channel-group 2 mode auto
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/3
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-2,69,100,201
 macro description switch
 !next command is internal.
 macro auto smartport dynamic_type switch
!
interface Port-Channel1
 description EthTrunk
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,69,100,201 tagged
 switchport general allowed vlan add 1 untagged
 macro description switch
 !next command is internal.
 macro auto smartport dynamic_type switch
!
interface Port-Channel2
 description X1Trunk
 switchport mode trunk
!
exit
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Questions about networking infrastructure and configuration belong on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you're using the same device and the same ethernet-cable when connecting to port 1 and port 19, correct?

would you mind to SSH into the switch and collect a "show run" for port 1 and 19?

...ok, with the config provided:

this is weird, port 1 is configured as routed port but the vlan-settings are still there.

my first try would be:

```
(in the ssh shell)

conf t
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
  switchport
  end
```

that should fix the vlan-membership.

a good practice for end-user-facing interfaces would be to add:

```
conf t
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
  spanning-tree portfast
  spanning-tree bpduguard enable
  end
```

Comment: Yes using the same cable and laptop to test.

Just added the result of "show run" to my original post.